# 2 ManyToMany relationship + 1 param in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables A and B.

I make a many to many Relationship with a pivot table called A_B

Now I need to make other ManyToMany Relationship between A_B and User ( U )

So I have another table A_B_U

Now, What I need and can't do it, is writing a relationship from A to A_B_U.

I set U to a vale, so A_B -> A_B_U is now a belongsTo Relationship, I should be able to access it easily, but I can't write it, I can write the first relationship, but then, I can't write the second one.

I don't know neither how to pass a param in ManyToMany Rel.

In fact, it shoud be a belongsTo, not ManyToMany so I'm a bit lost in all that....

Any Idea how to do it?

Comment: I am lost on the title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What it looks like

```
            category_tournament_user
                   /        \
    category_tournament    users
        /       \
tournaments   categories
```

### Migrations

```
Schema::create('tournaments', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_tournament', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('tournament_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_tournament_user', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('category_tournament_id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
});
```

### Models

```
class Tournament extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function categoryTournaments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryTournament::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function tournaments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class);
    }

    public function categoryTournament()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryTournament::class);
    }
}

class CategoryTournament extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category_tournament';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function tournament()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tournament::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'category_tournament_user');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function categoryTournaments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(CategoryTournament::class, 'category_tournament_user');
    }
}
```

### Get all users of a tournament

```
$tournament = App\Tournament::with('categoryTournaments.users')->find(1);

foreach($tournament->categoryTournaments as $categoryTournament) {

    // To get the category of the tournament, this will return an App\Category
    $category = $categoryTournament->category;

    // If you have a name column on your categories table...
    $categoryName = $category->name;


    // To get the tournament.
    $tournament = $categoryTournament->tournament;

    // To get the name of the tourament (if there is a name column)
    $tournamentName = $tournament->name;
    $tournament->created_at; // etc...


    // To get all the people participating in this tournament category
    foreach($categoryTournament->users as $user) {
        echo $user->email;
    }
}
```

If you need to figure out how to traverse the relationships (getting all tournaments and categories a user is participating in, etc...)  please feel free to ask.

### Starting at the User

```
// This will list all tournament and category names a user belongs to.
$user = App\User::with('categoryTournaments.tournament', 'categoryTournaments.category')->find($userId);
foreach($user->categoryTournaments as $categoryTournament) {
    echo 'Category Name: '.$categoryTournament->category->name;
    echo 'Tournament Name: '.$categoryTournament->tournament->name;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

#### Edit

- users and category_tournament make a belongsToMany relationship.
- categories and tournaments make a belongsToMany relationship.
- category_tournament also has a belongsTo to both tournaments and categories

There is a possibility we can further simplify this if you remove the tables `tournaments` and `categories` and drop all their columns right into `category_tournament`.  That way, you end up with only one belongsToMany relationship to manage.

Comment: I get all relations working as you say. But I don't understand well the last line. Can you please detail it?

Comment: Now, we can put names, it will be easier. A = Tournament, B = Category, U = User, what I need is getting all users in a tournament for instance

Comment: I'll rewrite the answer including the models.

Comment: First thing. I didn't test it, but I did it in a single query without relationships. So, If I need 2 foreach, I guess the eloquent method is not good in this case. 
Second thing, solution you propose sounds great. I will need to refactor a lot of stuff but it might be worth it. I could get easily all users from a tournament, but How should you get all users from a tournament category??? I don't know how to join 3 tables with eloquent

Comment: I thought about it, and the second solution is not posible. Categories list all categories available in app. Category_tournament list all categories available in the tournament. So If I have a category_tournament, and tournament_user, I will know in which tournament has registered the user, but I will not know in which category. I need a relation between category and user. So. I might resolve it by having a tournament_user, category_user and category_tournament.

Comment: You would know in which category.  The tournament is related to both a category and a user, it's just stored in different tables

Comment: oh, I see, you mean keep the category_tournament_user table, just add a tournament_user_table???

Comment: No, you are making this too hard.  If you know the user, you know the category of the tournaments they are in because you also know the tournaments.  Users are linked to tournaments and tournaments are linked to categories.  There is no need to again link the user directly to the category.

Comment: category_tournament are the categories available in this tournament. So if I join category_tournament and tournament_user, I will never have the relation between user, and the category he has registered... I will just know that user is registered to a tournament that has 10 availables categories. But within the 10 categories, user will only register 2

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now that you explain it that way.  You are right it would not work.

Comment: The original solution should work.  The problem with duplication would not be a problem for you now that I see it's intended to be that way.

Comment: The final question is: Is there a way to avoid the 1 of the 2 foreach loops? I know it is 2 many2many Rel, but one could be assume to be a hasOne Rel if I set UserId in the relation

Comment: If you already have the user id, you'd want to start at the user side of the relationships.  I'll update the answer again

Comment: It seems to be working, but I don't really understand the code... is it eager loading? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Yeah, the dot notation is eager loading nested relationships.  For example, the user isn't directly related to a category, you need to go through the categoryTournaments relation first, so you use categoryTournaments.category.  If you look in these models, you will see that these will match the function names which setup the relationships.  Also pay attention to the plurality of these.  categoryTournaments suggests there could be multiple `categoryTournament` returned so you'd need to loop through them.

Comment: You rock!!! I will need to work this, because it is not so clear to me, but this is exactly what nobody could tell me! Please accept 50 points of mine ;)

Comment: I find it very hard to understand this kind of relationship. Do you know where I can find some good docs?

Comment: I've modified the answer with the relationships which we are using.  Don't think of it as one large relationship but a few smaller relationships.  Also gave a suggestion how we can simplify this.